# How do I get my test class to cover the extension controller?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

I am getting only 1% code coverage - please help on how to get it fully covered!
My page (minus all the html which references variables from the class):

```
<apex:page id="ApplicationFormPDF" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false"
       standardController="Application__c" extensions="ApplicationFormControllerExtension"
       docType="html-5.0" renderAs="{!IF($CurrentPage.parameters.renderAs == 'html', '', 'pdf')}">
```

Then the Extension class(simplified - the rest is similar as in all being definitions and getters/setters only):

```
public with sharing class ApplicationFormControllerExtension {
private final Application__c application;

public ApplicationFormControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    application = (Application__c) controller.getRecord();
}

public Account account {
    get {
        if (account == NULL) {
            account = [
                    SELECT Id, Name, IsPersonAccount, PersonEmail, PersonMobilePhone, Phone FROM Account
                    WHERE Id = :application.Account__c
            ];
        }
        return account;
    }
    private set;
}

public boolean isCompany {
    get { return account.Entity_Type__c == 'Company'; }
}

public List<Signatory> signatories {
    get {
        if (signatories == NULL) {
            signatories = new List<Signatory>();

            for (Account_Role__c relationship : signatoryRelationshipsForSigning) {
                signatories.add(new Signatory(relationship.Secondary_Account__r));
            }
        }

        return signatories;
    }
    private set;
}

class Signatory {
    public String signatoryName { get; private set; }
    public String companyName { get; private set; }
    public String signatoryRole { get; private set; }

    public Signatory(Account signatory) {
        signatoryName = signatory.Name;
        companyName = '';
        signatoryRole = '';
    }


}
```

}

Then my test class I've done this below. It runs without errors, but only covers the controller declaration line!

```
@IsTest
public class ApplicationFormControllerExtension_test {

@TestSetup
static void setup()
{
    AutomationEnabled__c setting = TestData.createAutomationSetting();
    insert setting;
}

static testmethod void ApplicationFormTest(){
    TEST.startTest();
    Account customerAccount = TestData.createAccount('Organisation');
    insert customerAccount;

    Account issuerAccount = TestData.createAccount('Issuer');
    issuerAccount.Membership_Status__c = 'Approved';
    insert issuerAccount;

    TEST.stopTest();

    Application__c application = new Application__c();
    application.Account__c = issueAccount.id;
    application.Quantity_Applied_For__c = 10000;
    application.Issue__c = issue.id;
    insert application;

    // Setup pages and pass through parameters
    PageReference pageRef = page.ApplicationFormPDF;
    test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    Apexpages.StandardController stdController = new Apexpages.StandardController(application);        
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('appl',application.id);
    ApplicationFormControllerExtension controller = new ApplicationFormControllerExtension(stdController);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to call all your methods after you set your page as current page using your extension class instance.

```
Apexpages.StandardController stdController = new Apexpages.StandardController(application);
ApplicationFormControllerExtension controller = new ApplicationFormControllerExtension(stdController);
PageReference pageRef = page.ApplicationFormPDF;  
pageRef.getParameters().put('id',application.id); 
test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
//Call your methods from extension class using your extension instance
controller.yourMethodName(); //call extension methods
Account acc = controller.account //get the value of extension account
//similarly get the values of remaining getters   
//Make the assertions using system.assert or system.assertEquals for all the methods or for all the getters
```

If you have only getters and setters in your class, then you will have to access those getters in your test class in order to cover those lines.

Also, you should write assert statements in test class to make sure that your code works as expected. Assertions can be made using System.assert statements or System.assertEquals statements.

Comment: Hi Vijay, I'm still getting only 1% coverage. The page is called from a custom link for the Application object (/apex/ApplicationFormPDF?Id={!Application__c.Id})

Comment: Hi @Irene, you will then have to call your methods which you created in your extension class post setting your page as current page. Also, I updated the answer to have `id` as parameter instead of `appl`. If you have all getters and setters, try to get those values in your test class as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes I spotted the parameter too, and you're right in that I have to access each getter/setter in order to get code coverage - very painful! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Irene, code coverage means that the specific code has been invoked in your tests. The outline that Vijay Ganji provided gives you some coverage, but importantly this is not actually testing the controller extension class. To test the behaviour you need to have expectations as to what the controller should do and check that it is meeting those expectations by using System.assert or System.assertEquals. See https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro for help here.

Comment: Hi @Phil thanks and yes I do know that and will ensure that too of course. This was just a difficult one to get coverage on.